# .htaccess rewrite, fail with uri string

Tags: .htaccess

`/node` works fine but when i append a string query, `/node/1234` or even just another `/` then the page is not fully operational. (javascript fails)

```
RewriteEngine On
# Turn on the rewriting engine
RewriteRule ^node/?$ index.php?req=node [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^node/(.*)$ index.php?req=node&con=$1 [NC,L]
```

Is there more than just a regex for all to pass anything after `/node`?

Comment: javascript breaks. the source looks fine so i'm not 100% sure why it breaks. this is the only thing that changes between working & not working

Comment: Probably the path to the scripts is wrong. Since you do not make an external redirect you have to rewrite the script references too.

Comment: Open your page in chrome dev tool and see if you're getting 404 for JS / css

Comment: i get:
`SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<'TypeError: $(...).tubular is not a function` with the 2nd rule included with the original one. there also was a encoding warning thats been solved

Comment: What order are your rules in?

Comment: @Jon Lin please see updated question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by changing the HTML script src from : `js/jquery.tubular.1.0.js` `//www.example.com/js/jquery.tubular.1.0.js`. Obviously where example.com would be the real URL

Comment: is there any security implications with this method?